# Creating an if method in php with what I selected in a query?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Hello everyone I have created a download script on php but unfortunately it is not working it is displaying "you have not paid yet"(echo I created), when in my MYSQL database my account did infact have paid = 1 and I tried paid = 2. Can anyone help me fix this?

```
<?php
$user = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `as_users`");
$username = $userInfo['username'];
if (!isset($username)) {
  $username = $_GET['username'];
}
    $mysqli = new mysqli('****', '***', '****', '****');
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT paid FROM as_users WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
            if ($paid == 1 || $paid == 2) {
            echo "hello great job paying";
            } else {
            echo "you have not paid yet";
}           
            ?>
```

I think my if method is wrong because I have never created an if method of what I select in a query I made so sorry if this is a noob question.

Comment: `$paid` is never defined.

Comment: how would I define $paid? if its the thing I selected

Comment: selected from the prepare statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined `$paid`. You need to use the `bind_result` method followed by `fetch`. More info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php and here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

```
<?php
$user = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `as_users`");
$username = $userInfo['username'];
if (!isset($username)) {
  $username = $_GET['username'];
}
    $mysqli = new mysqli('****', '***', '****', '****');
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT paid FROM as_users WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($paid);
    $stmt->fetch();
    if ($paid == 1 || $paid == 2) {
            echo "hello great job paying";
    } else {
            echo "you have not paid yet";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a prepared statement you may bind output variables to get the data values you need from the query but the variables must be bound after execution.
see: 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: thanks my code now looks correct but unfortunately I am getting this error Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()  when I include 

 $res = $stmt->get_result();
 $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
 printf("paid = %s (%s)\n", $row['paid'], gettype($row['paid']));